# Exporting table data as JSON to JSON file from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few questions on formatting data as it gets export properly to a JSON file.

I have setup this query so far which joins tables and select the needed fields for exporting to a JSON file after generating a JSON object from the data:

```
Select JSON_OBJECT(
    'tableAId' VALUE a.TABLE_A_ID,
    'code' VALUE b.CODE,
    'someOtherId' VALUE a.SOME_OTHER_ID,
    'startDate' VALUE TO_DATE(a.START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    'endDate' VALUE TO_DATE(a.END_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    'lastUpdateDate' VALUE TO_DATE(a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    'creationDate' VALUE TO_DATE(a.CREATION_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    'locations' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG
    (
        JSON_OBJECT 
        (
        'id' VALUE l.ID,
        'city' VALUE l.CITY,
        'state' VALUE l.STATE,
        'country' VALUE l.COUNTRY
        )
    ) FORMAT JSON
)
from TABLE_A a
left join TABLE_B b on a.COMMON_ID = b.COMMON_ID
left join TABLE_L l on a.TABLE_A_ID = l.TABLE_A_ID
WHERE b.CODE is not null
GROUP BY  
    a.TABLE_A_ID,
    b.CODE,
    a.SOME_OTHER_ID,
    a.START_DATE,
    a.END_DATE,
    a.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
    a.CREATION_DATE;
```

Currently, I'm running into two issues and I have questions on it.

1. How do I convert my datetimes to dates with a Zoned Date Time? That is, I want to convert my datetime to UTC Zoned Date but not sure how to do that here?
2. Currently with the TO_DATE I have setup, the year is off starting with something like 0034 which seems wrong. I noticed if I removed the TO_DATE conversion the date works but not in the format I want ( at least for startDate, endDate because the have the times attached to them 00:00:00 albeit they're saved with just the date in the db).
3. How do I group my root object to be nested under an overall key like for example I wanted to nest all objects under "neededObjects" ? I tried to setup something similar like I did with locations where it's value is JSON_ARRAYAGG and under there is a new JSON_OBJECT that I want. However, I do get compile errors with doing this approach from the root, so maybe I'm doing it wrong. What should it be?

Does the above seems good in terms of query? I want it to mimic as close as to a typical api response as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Never use `to_date` on date columns (I presume `CREATION_DATE` to be of `date` datatype), because they are already dates that **have no any human-readable format**. Casting them to dates again causes implicit type conversion to the string: `to_date(date, 'format')` is equal to `to_date(to_char(date, (select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')), 'format')`. To consider timestamp at some time zone use [`at time zone` expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Datetime-Expressions.html).

Comment: In the DB, my startDate looks like this 2024-07-27 and my creationDate looks like: 2023-07-23 10:20:12. However, when I try to_date above that's when I get errors.

Comment: Also running into an issue where the startDate keeps the time 00:00:00 when I run the above even though it's just a date object